# Layout does not appear when replacing a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am trying to replace a fragment within a container with a different one. I made a Toast in the new fragment which is displayed but the layout does not show.

Here is where I replace the fragment:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title", textContentList.get(position).getTitle());
            bundle.putString("crated", textContentList.get(position).getCreated());
            bundle.putString("author", textContentList.get(position).getAuthor());
            bundle.putString("fullContent", textContentList.get(position).getFullContent());
            MessageDetailsFragment messageDetailsFragment = new MessageDetailsFragment();
            messageDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            replaceFragment(messageDetailsFragment);

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Here is my fragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text_container"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
android:background="?android:colorBackground"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    style="@style/headings"
    android:text="Author"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/message_details_author"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/subTxt_messageDetails"
    android:text="Receiver"
    android:id="@+id/message_details_receiver"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    style="@style/dividerLine" />

<TextView
    style="@style/headings"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Title"
    android:id="@+id/message_details_title"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/subTxt_messageDetails"
    android:text="Date"
    android:id="@+id/message_details_date"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    style="@style/dividerLine" />

<TextView
    android:text="Full content"
    style="@style/subTxt_messageDetails"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/message_details_full_content"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/subTxt_messageDetails"
    android:text="Sent by SMS"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/message_sent_by"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my new fragment:

```
public class MessageDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

private String title, created, author, fullContent;
private TextView textViewTitle, textViewDate, textViewAuthor, textViewFullContent;
private Bundle bundle;
private Context context;

public MessageDetailsFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bundle = this.getArguments();
    title = bundle.getString("title");
    created = bundle.getString("created");
    author = bundle.getString("author");
    fullContent = bundle.getString("fullContent");
    context = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message_details, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Toast.makeText(context, "ADDASD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    textViewTitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.message_details_title);
    textViewTitle.setText(title);
    textViewDate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.message_details_date);
    textViewDate.setText(created);
    textViewAuthor = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.message_details_author);
    textViewAuthor.setText(author);
    textViewFullContent = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.message_details_full_content);
    textViewFullContent.setText(fullContent);

}
}
```

Comment: Your layout is incomplete. It has no closing tag and references are being made to views that it does not contain. e.g imageView  Correct your layout then try again if you still have an issue

Comment: Thanks. I removed the view that was not supposed to be there and the closing tag didn't get displayed here for some reason. I still have the same issue tough

Comment: Also, unrelated but in your `OnCreate`, you assign `getActivity` to the context variable. This will always be null as the activity will not be set until later in the lifecycle.  No need to keep a references to the context, you can call getActivity later when you need it and perform a check for null before you use it. Your Activity could get finished but the reference would still exist to the finished Activity and so the Fragment could cause a crash when it is used

Comment: Again unrelated but, you have a typo in your bundle. `crated` but the fragment looks for `created`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. Turns out that I tried to insert the fragment into a viewpager which I also use in the application. By creating a new FrameLayout and inserting it into that I resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is not reproducible as it refers to styles etc not given so it is difficult to say for sure so generally speaking....

To debug a Fragment layout, first clear it of everything except the parent ViewGroup. Give it an easily identifiable colour so you can see that it is actually appearing in your app when you initiate it.

If it appears, the problem is your layout. If not, it is most likely your code.

Once you have done this, you can gradually add your other views.

e.g

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@color/Red"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </LinearLayout
```